# Adding only N rows to a new table from a source table in MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to insert only N rows to a *new table* from a *source table* using

`Select * into NewTable from SourceTable where  ......`

I have no idea about the *source table* columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select * into NewTable...` will create a `new table`.
[you cannot insert the data into an existing table like this. You have to use `insert into...`]

If you want to insert N rows then try;

```
select top N * into NewTable sourcetable where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * INTO NewTable
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) AS Row
    FROM SourceTable
) t
WHERE t.Row <= N
```